# abortbroadcast for incoming call

Tags: abortbroadcast

I know there has been a lot of discussion already on the subject of abortBroadcast for incomming calls. Is their anyone who has found a way around this problem. I'm trying to create an app that when an incoming phonecall is answered the native incallscreen does not show.

For the moment the he only solution I have found is to create your own custom ROM, but that seems is bit much for just one app.

thanx

Comment: The only "solution" I found was giving up. This seems to be an impossible task, but I still hope.

Answer (score 1):

Since there's no proper way of using `abortBroadcast()`, as `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE` is not being received via an ordered broadcast (no `sendOrderedBroadcast()` call, but `sendBroadcast()` instead – I've simply checked this by calling `isOrderedBroadcast()` in my receiver), all receivers must receive **this** intent "at the same time". But things start happening even before the broadcast.

Furthermore, nothing "legally receivable" happens before the call to `sendBroadcast()`, as thoroughly yet briefly described in **[this blog post](http://wangling.me/2009/08/why-it-is-impossible-to-intercept-incoming-calls-on-android.html)**. And that, unfortunately, means we'd have to go down to system level and, among other tasks, "abort broadcast before broadcast", either by applying a custom ROM, or otherwise modifying the device.

If you still want to do this, I believe custom ROM may be the way to go. And I so hope to be corrected. Only possible solution and that for rooted devices, in my opinion, lies in finding anything "legally receivable" that comes in time.